# Possible way to do `~{do_something}`?

Tags: dsl, crystal-lang

I'm making a DSL in crystal, and I'm trying to get a syntax like `~{do_something}`

I tried something like this:

```
def ~(&block)
  block.call
end

def my_func
  puts "hello"
end

~ { my_func }
```

But all I get is this error:

```
Error in line 11: undefined method '~' for Tuple(Nil)
```

https://carc.in/#/r/1oyv

I tried to replace `{...}` with `do; ...; end` without much success:

```
~ do; my_func; end
```

And I got:

```
Syntax error in eval:11: expecting token 'EOF', not 'end'
```

1. Can you explain why to I get theses error ?
2. Is there a way to make this syntax to work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is parsed as a bitwise complement unary operator (see the [language reference](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/operators.html)), it is only valid as a method name when being called on an object (`foo.~`) or used an an operator (`~foo`, does the same as previous example).

In your code, `~ { my_func }` is being parsed as a tuple literal (`{my_func}`, type `Tuple(Nil)` as `my_func` returns nil) with the `~` operator used on it. As `Tuple` doesn't implement that operator (it's not binary, you can't take a bitwise complement of it), you get that error. For the second error, `do; code; end` blocks cannot exist on their own so you get said syntax error.

I don't think there's a way to implement the exact syntax you want, choose a valid method name for your `~` function.

Comment: Thanks, currently I fall back to something like: `var = ~ MyObj.new { my_func }`